# VsCode: "Go To Symbol" is broken, does not work if it contains colons

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to find the symbol `Exceptionhandler::SignalHandler` in vscode's "Go To Symbol" by typing this: `#Exceptionhandler::SignalHandler` (see the screenshot).

It works perfectly fine:

- if I type just `#Exceptionhandler`
- or just `#SignalHandler`,

**but it breaks if I type `#Exceptionhandler::SignalHandler`**.

[image]

### Are there any workarounds?

Comment: list what relevant language support extensions you have installed, linking to their marketplace pages and showing what version of them you have installed. Please also provide some minimal code to make it easier to reproduce the behaviour (see the instructions for providing a [mre]).

Comment: do you want to go to a declaration? or to the definition?

Comment: @starball I would like to go definition.

Comment: @starball, before going into these details (like versions, extensions, minimal repro, etc...) I just wanted to know if ANYONE can make VsCode resolve symbols in the form `ClassName::MethodName` (if this is possible at all). Does vscode resolve symbols in this form?

Comment: it probably could. it's just a matter of there being or writing an extension that does that.